# PHPMailer error: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I try to google all the morning and i think i need Stackoverflow now!

I wrote a simple script to send a mail (from hotmail to gmail)
but i get this error:

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)SMTP Connect() failed. Error

This is the code:

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/phpMailer/class.phpMailer.php");
require_once("../includes/phpMailer/class.smtp.php");


$to_name = "RECEIVER NAME";
$to = "RECEIVER@gmail.com";


$subject = "Mail test at " . strftime("%T", time());

$message = "This is a test message";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);


$from_name = "MY NAME";
$from = "MY_EMAIL@hotmail.it";


$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "MY USERNAME (hotmail)";
$mail->Password = "MY PASSWORD (hotmail)";


$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;

$result = $mail->Send();

echo $result ? 'Sent' : 'Error';

?>
```

Another info is that not even the standard mail() function worked, and checking php info i found this:

sendmail_from - MY PROPER MAIL (hotmail)

sendmail_path - no value

SMTP -  localhost

smtp_port - 25

Thank you!!

Comment: is your hosting company / isp blocking the ports?

Answer (score 5):

I believe port 25 is blocked on smtp.live.com.  I cannot connect to smtp.live.com:25 from here either.  Try using port 587 instead, with TLS.  So, it would be:

```
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Comment: I try, but i get two errors:
This for the port:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 BLU0-SMTP125.phx.gbl Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service [...]  Service closing transmission channel SMTP Connect() failed. Error

And this for tls:

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [<a href='streams.crypto'>streams.crypto</a>]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php on line 254

And also this error in the end:

CLIENT -> SMTP: quit SMTP -> FROM SERVER:SMTP -> ERROR: SMTP server rejected quit command: SMTP Connect() failed. Error

Comment: looks like you might not have the necessary encryption libraries installed on your server for TLS.  You will need TLS or SSL to send through smtp.live.com.  As a workaround, do you have a gmail account?  If so, you can send through smtp.gmail.com, without SSL or TLS encryption, on port 25.

Comment: Yes i have gmail account. Do you suggest to try the reverse, to send from gmail to hotmail?

Comment: No,  I'm suggesting using gmail to send the messages, instead of Hotmail.  So, it would be

    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 25;

and get rid of the SMTPSecure line.

Comment: I try, but i am still getting error:


SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)SMTP Connect() failed. Error

Comment: If i change port to 587 i get this phrase in the error message: 

Must issue a STARTTLS command first

- What does this means?

Comment: If, i try to add this  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";   i get this error message instead:

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (0)SMTP Connect() failed. Error

Comment: Your PHP is not configured for encryption.  So, you can't use SSL or TLS, unless you reconfigure (and possibly re-compile) your PHP.  But, you should still be able to connect to send through smtp.gmail.com on port 25, or port 587, without SSL or TLS.  Are you saying that you are getting 'failed to connect to server' when you try to connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 25 and port 587?  If so, can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: Thank you for reply. What can i do to configure php? i have to change some settings in php.ini?
USing this code:
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
i get this error:
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server.

Using this code: 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;

i get this error:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP v18sm1146165lbd.5 - gsmtp CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO localhost SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com [...] Must issue a STARTTLS command first.Connect() failed. Error

Comment: OK.  I think your host is blocking outgoing connections on port 25, so that's why you can't connect on port 25.  You're able to connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 587, but gmail requires you to use TLS when you connect on 587, and your PHP is not configured for encryption.  So, you're hosed both ways.  You're on a WAMP server, so I can't tell you how to enable encryption in your PHP - that might be a separate question.  In the meantime, you might want to find another outgoing mail server that will allow you to make an unencrypted connection on some port other than port 25.

Comment: Check out www.ultrasmtp.com.  You can connect to this server unencrypted on port 587.

Comment: Can i ask you what is STARTTLS and how can i issue a STARTTLS command?

Comment: With TLS, the connection starts off unencrypted (in plain text), then then encryption is enabled by both sides during the connection.  The STARTTLS command is what enables encryption during the connection.  You (or your PHP code) would not issue this command - phpmailer normally does this automatically if you have $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'.  But, in your case, it's not working because you don't have encryption enabled in your PHP build.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But how can i enable the encryption?

Comment: You're getting a warning from PHP, 'this stream does not support SSL/crypto'.  So, this means that your PHP is not configured to enable encryption.  Your running on WAMP, so I couldn't tell you how to fix this.  You might want to post a separate question on SO, or perhaps posting on serverfault might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this problem, try this

Check whether your PHP is using **openSSL** extension or not...!

1. Edit your **php.ini** from your installed php folder
2. Search for **extension=php_openssl.dll**
3. The initial will look like this **;extension=php_openssl.dll**
4. Remove the ';' and it will look like this **extension=php_openssl.dll**
5. If you can't find the **extension=php_openssl.dll**, add this line **extension=php_openssl.dll**.
6. Then restart your Xampp or LAMP or APACHE server (depends upon which of these you're using).

Hope this method shall solve your problem...

Comment: Phew, thanks! This answer saved me a bunch of trouble. The OpenSSL PHP extension isn't enabled by default on a fresh install, apparantly (CentOS 6, PHP 5.6).