# SMTP error while using PHPMailer for gmail even after connecting to gmail SMTP

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to send mails from my "gmail" account using PHPMailer, operating from localhost. I am getting an error like this in my browser:

```
Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed
```

The php code used for sending mail is as follows:

```
<?php
function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)
{
    //require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    $from = "mysite.com";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();// use SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    //// enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";// SMTP host
    $mail->Port = 587;// set the SMTP port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";  // SMTP  username
    $mail->Password   = "mypass";  // SMTP password
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
    $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
    $mail->msgHTML("the body of the mail");
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo "Message sent!";}
    //$mail->Subject    = $subject;
    //$mail->MsgHTML($body);
    //$address = $to;
   // $mail->AddAddress($address, $to);
    //$mail->Send(); 
}
?>
```

I have tried a lot of things from different permutations of tsl/ssl and port, but all in vain. I also `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` to check the connection to gmailSMTP which gave a positive result as shown below:

```
Trying 74.125.130.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ml6sm5492964pdb.69 - gsmtp
```

I am little new to PHP and have been trying to solve the problem from last 6hrs. Any ideas for the same? 
Sorry in advance if the problem is stupid.

Comment: Is your server configured to send emails ? Try using the regular `mail()` function first and see if that works ? The error may not even be PHPMailer error.

Comment: Also, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672960/phpmailer-error-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server (or other questions related to that one)

Comment: When using PHPMailer's SMTP client, it doesn't use `mail()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should base your code on [the provided gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). You're trying to use `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` with `Port = 587`. That won't work: use `tls` with port 587. You're also making a mess of including the files. Maybe you should try reading the docs? Even the example in the readme does this correctly.

Comment: I already tried these settings before posting, but that didn't worked. The above piece of code is the final one that I tried after trying different settings.

Comment: I commented the include for `class.phpmailer.php` and used `tls` instead of `ssl` and it worked. Thanks man, for the help.